# Why is the period of $f$, $\pi$?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

I came across a problem, which asked to compute the period of the function $$f(x)=3^{\sec^2x-\tan^2 x}.$$

The answer provided was $\pi$.

I don't get how.

Comment: I have never seen so many incorrect solutions so quickly posted, then deleted.

Comment: @James: There were $2$, and it is debatable whether they were incorrect.

Comment: @JonasMeyer It was about to be $3$ but I couldn't comment on a deleted answer.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Well leaving the debate aside, my statement about my personal experience is still correct.

Comment: @oliveeuler: I don't understand your comment.  How was it about to be 3?  And how does that relate to trying to comment on a deleted answer?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I meant that I was about to add an incorrect answer as a comment on the incorrect answer; I couldn't do so as it was deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $\sec^2 x- \tan^2 x= 1$ for all $x$ except those in the form $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ (where $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ are undefined. Thus, $f(x) = 3^{\sec^2 x- \tan^2 x}  = 3^1 = 3$ for all $x$ except those in the form $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$, which are evenly spaced every $\pi$ units. Thus, $f(x)$ has period $\pi$.

Comment: Yeah..that makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

It is a constant function. It is technically undefined at the points JimmyK4542 mentions.  In order for the identity $f(x+p)=f(x)$ to hold, is is required that the domain $D$ of $f$ satisfies $D+p=D$ (where $D+p$ is defined as $\{x+p:x\in D\}$).  For the domain in question, this occurs whenever $p$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.  Because the function is constant, this is the only requirement.

However, that is unsatisfying because the function is essentially the constant function $3$, which has no smallest period.  The singularities are removable, and in many contexts it is useful to remove them (after briefly recognizing and acknowledging that there are singularities to be removed).

Comment: How could you remove the singularities if the function is undefined at those points? Do you mean redefining the function?

Comment: @oliveeuler: The definition of removable singularity I have in mind is the following: $f$ is defined on $D\setminus\{a\}$ where $a$ is a limit point of $D$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.   Extend $f$ to $a$ by defining $f(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.  I guess this is what you mean by redefining the function.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying.